# Is it possible to use a Odata Custom Action POST as trigger?

Tags: post, asp.net-core, odata, action

I want to remove a User-Relation from my database on logout. Therefor i only need a trigger from the Frontend, so that i can get the User-Relation from the HttpContext. The Method lies in the Main-Entity-Controller of my application. The reason for this is, that i would have to write a controller for the Entity "UserRelation" only because of this method.

My Remove-Action looks like this

In Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> RemoveUser()
{
   var userRelation = dbContext.UserRelation.FindAsync(GetId());

   //some validation

   dbContext.Remove(userRelation );
   await dbContext.SaveAsync();

   return Ok();
}
```

In the ModelBuilder

```
builder.EntityType<MainEntity>().Action("RemoveUser");
```

API-Call

```
/odata/MainController/RemoveUser
```

The Postman-Call always ends in a 404. How can i access this method. And is it all in all bad practice, to set the method in this controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

If you set the Action like this, it works fine.

```
builder.EntityType<MainEntity>().Collection.Action("RemoveUser");
```